# Vlookup in VBA for a Date and keep getting 1004 error

Tags: vba, vlookup

I don't know what to do, I'm just trying to do a vlookup where is finds a date in another sheet and pulls it in but I keep getting 1004 error, I've searched for hours on other forums and nothing seems to work, please help! Here's my code:

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim StoreData As Range
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Set StoreData = Sheets("List of Stores").Range("A2:C" & lastrow)

Sheets("SJ360 for Source 140").Select
Range("H1").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

On Error GoTo myerrorhandler:
Dim x
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SJ360 for Source 140")
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("I2", StoreData, 3, False)
Range("H2").Value = x


End With
```

Comment: `"I2"` needs to be `Range("I2")`

Comment: OMG I feel so stupid, thank you!

Comment: One more question, I want to drag it down and so I'm using: `Dim FillFormula As Variant
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SJ360 for Source 140")
    Range("H2").Select
    Sheets("SJ360 for Source 140").Select
    FillFormula="VLookup(Range("I2"), StoreData, 3, False)"
    .Range("H2:H&lastrow").Formula = FillFormula
    .Range("H2:H&lastrow").FillDown`

Comment: Anything that starts with `One more question` should be its own question.

Comment: When I do this ^ it says that `range("I2")` is wrong, any ideas to why it won't allow me to fill the vlookup down?

Comment: You change the whole thing, you do not use `Range()` inside a formula, only vba.  You switched from vba to formula. They are two separate entities and are treated differently.